# emacs で特定のモード ( js-mode ) のときだけ indent 幅を 2 にしたい

Tags: emacs, elisp

emacs で、 js-mode のときだけ、 indent 幅を 2 にしたくなりました。これは、どのように実現できるでしょうか。

Comment: `describe-variable` で `js*indent` と入力して TAB キーで補完すると、表示される候補変数群の中にそれらしい変数が表示されている事と思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@metropolis さんの助言に従った結果、 `js-indent-level` を customize することでやりたいことが実現できました。